# Unity indicators slowly disappear after suspending laptop on dual monitor configuration

Tags: 11.04, unity, nvidia, indicator, multiple-monitors

I have one quite annoying issues with Unity behaviour after waking laptop up from suspend.
Second issue is that after waking up, list of indicators on second, smaller monitor move small amount to right, making them gradually disappear each wake up.

I have nvidia GS9200M graphic card, and run on nvidia binary drivers from Ubuntu repository.

Is there any way could stop those indicators to travel out of my second monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same behaviour as described by you occurs when running the traditional notification area with white-listed icons.

That problem is already known as [Bug 750481](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/750481), I attached your probem to that report.

Comment: Hmmm... I see now it's more accurate description of this problem in this bug report